# synchronizing scrolling between 2 divs with different text size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't find a way to synchronize two divs, with the same text, but different text size and padding.
I have two divs, one with a markdown text, and the other one with the html render of the markdown and I want to synchronize the `scrollTop` between the divs.

For an example, look [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/editor)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the example of synchronizing two divs at: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvn1ngby/)

**HTML**

Given you have two divs placed next to each other horizontally. Each of the divs contain another div and it is scrollable vertically:

```
<div class="outer" id="div1">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer" id="div2">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

This is just to make two outer divs lie next to each other at the same baseline and make it scrollable vertically.

```
div.outer
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:320px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

div.outer > div
{
    width:100%;
    height:3000px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

The simplest approach is, bind `scroll` event to each of the outer divs, take the `scrollTop` value and apply to its counterpart div as follows:

```
$('#div1').scroll(function(){
    $('#div2').scrollTop( $('#div1').scrollTop() );
});

$('#div2').scroll(function(){
    $('#div1').scrollTop( $('#div2').scrollTop() );
});
```

So when you scroll on the left div, it synchronizes the right div, and vice-versa.

Comment: This doesn't really work if your generated preview is larger than your markdown. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvn1ngby/6/). Stackedit calls this "scroll link" feature (see their README). The code for this extension is [open-source](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/82ba08fbfdc0c64036453d6fab24027565e5409c/public/res/extensions/scrollSync.js). Would be cool to have this decoupled from their code. This enables to align varies content depending on the current view port.