# Angular 4 scroll two seperate elements togther

Tags: angular

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpmeyf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I'm capturing the `scrollLeft` of one element as it's scrolled.

Is it possible to update the second div with the `scrollLeft` number so both div scroll left and right together?

The elements have to be separate but I need them to scroll together.

Or is there a simpler way to do this in Angular.

I had this working outside of Angular with jQuery but I don't want to use jQuery in Angular.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  isNavbarCollapsed = true;

  private scrollLeft: number
  //private scrolLTwo: HTMLElement = 

  onScroll(event: Event) {
    this.scrollLeft = (event.target as HTMLElement).scrollLeft;
    //console.log(this.scrollLeft);
    this.updateScroll();
  }

  updateScroll(){
    //Update second scrolling element
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [synchronizing scrolling between 2 divs with different text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178866/synchronizing-scrolling-between-2-divs-with-different-text-size)

Comment: That question has a jQuery answer. I want to try and do this with Angular and not jQuery. I had a jQuery solution that didn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just get a reference to the second `<div>` and set it's scroll left to the same amount:

```html
<div class="container" (scroll)="scrollTwo.scrollLeft = scrollOne.scrollLeft" #scrollOne>
    ...
</div>
<div class="container" #scrollTwo>
    ...
</div>
```

If you want to have more complicated logic in your component to manage what the scroll amount should be, you can just get the reference to the two DOM nodes via `@ViewChild`:

```html
<div class="container" (scroll)="updateScroll()" #scrollOne>
    ...
</div>
<div class="container" #scrollTwo>
    ...
</div>
```

```js
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('scrollOne') scrollOne: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('scrollTwo') scrollTwo: ElementRef;

  updateScroll(){
    const scrollOne = this.scrollOne.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    const scrollTwo = this.scrollTwo.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    // do logic and set
    scrollTwo.scrollLeft = scrollOne.scrollLeft;
  }
}
```

You don't have to get the references via `@ViewChild`. You could rather just pass them into the method that is called:

```html
<div class="container" (scroll)="updateScroll(scrollOne, scrollTwo)" #scrollOne>
    ...
</div>
<div class="container" #scrollTwo>
    ...
</div>
```

```js
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent  {
  updateScroll(scrollOne: HTMLElement, scrollTwo: HTMLElement){
    // do logic and set
    scrollTwo.scrollLeft = scrollOne.scrollLeft;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular CDK now provides [cdkScrollable and ScrollDispatcher](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#cdkscrollable-and-scrolldispatcher). Just add `cdkScrollable` directive to all your scrollable elements which need to be kept in sync and then add this logic to your component:

```js
this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((scrollable: CdkScrollable) => {
  if (typeof scrollable == 'undefined') {
    return true;
  }
  const left = scrollable.measureScrollOffset('left');

  Array.from(this.scrollDispatcher.scrollContainers.keys())
    .filter(otherScrollable => otherScrollable && otherScrollable !== scrollable)
    .forEach(otherScrollable => {
      if (otherScrollable.measureScrollOffset('left') !== left) {
        otherScrollable.scrollTo({left});
      }
    });
});
```

Do not forget to unsubscribe from this subscription when the component is destroyed. And also inject `ScrollDispatcher` service in the constructor:

```js
public constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't even need to use CdkScrollable directive since I'm using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport and it just works out of the box.

Comment: scrollable is undefined for me inside the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add: if we use any material component as the scrollable element then we have to use this code:

```
<mat-grid-tile
  #scrollOne
  (scroll)="updateScroll(scrollOne, scrollTwo)">
</mat-grid-list>
<mat-grid-tile
  #scrollTwo
  (scroll)="updateScroll(scrollTwo, scrollOne)">
</mat-grid-list>


updateScroll(scrollOne: any, scrollTwo: any) {
   const scrO = scrollOne._element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
   const scrT = scrollTwo._element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

   scrT.scrollLeft = scrO.scrollLeft;
   scrT.scrollTop = scrO.scrollTop; 
}
```